# Combine two columns in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there an easy way to combine two columns in a datagridview? Hide the two and use their data together in a new one perhaps?

Data is coming in from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is way if you aren't using binding then you just do it like this:

```
foreach( DataRow dr in dt.Rows )
{
 DataGridView1.Rows.Add( new object [] { (int)dr["first_col"] + (int)dr["first_col"] } );
}
```

If you are using binding create Computed Column in the table an bind it to column.